# Django Admin datetime in EST

Tags: python, django, datetime

In my application I need to show some datetimes in the admin section in `EST` timezone. I have the following configuration in `settings.py`:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = False
```

Users chose differente timezones and works fine for them, ie; `Thursday, May 16, 2019 12:00 AM EDT`

But I want to show datetime in `EST` timezone in the admin section. Currently it will show all times in `UTC` as expected. I tried the following:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone  
from django.contrib import admin

TZ = timezone('EST')

@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'scheduled_date')

    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('name', 'scheduled_date')}),
    )

    def scheduled_date(self, obj):
        date = datetime(obj.scheduled_date, tzinfo=TZ)
        return date
```

However the admin section is still showing time in UTC for `scheduled_date`

Answer (score 2):

You can create a middleware that will change the timezone at runtime for every request coming from Admin.
For Instance:

```
import pytz
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin


class AdminTimezoneMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):    
    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.path.startswith('/admin'):
            timezone.activate(pytz.timezone('EST'))
```

Don't forget to add that on settings.MIDDLEWARE array.

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
   ...
   'yourapp.AdminTimezoneMiddleware'
]
```